# [JQUERY][PHP] AJAX request returns OK but it goes to error

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make JQUERY and PHP communicate with some strange results

Here's the JQuery

```
$.ajax({
 type : "GET",
 url : "background.php",
 dataType: 'json',
 success : function(response){
  alert("OK: " + immagini);
 },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  eval('var immagini = xhr.responseText');
  alert("CODE: " + xhr.status);
  alert("ERROR: " + immagini + "\n\n\nTIPO: " + typeof immagini);
 }
});
```

And here's the PHP

```
<?php
 include "amministrazione/config.php";
 include "amministrazione/database.php";
 header("Content-type: application/json");
 $db = new DB($db_server,$db_name,$db_user,$db_pass);
 echo $db->loadBackgroundImages();
?>
```

And finally there is the answer I build from PHP function

```
{'immagini':[{'image': 'gallery/alto.jpg'},{'image': 'gallery/esterno.jpg'},{'image': 'gallery/gelateria.jpg'},{'image': 'gallery/vitelli.jpg'}]};
```

Strange thing is that the Jquery ends up in the error handler even if code is 200... how can I fix this?

This shouldn't be a Cross-Domain problem, since they are on the same directory on EasyPHP, or am I wrong?

Many thanks,

Tiwiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change single quote to double quote in your json

```
{"immagini":[{"image": "gallery/alto.jpg"},{"image": "gallery/esterno.jpg"},{"image": "gallery/gelateria.jpg"},{"image": "gallery/vitelli.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: That was the deal :) Many thanks for the answer; I didn't think JSON would just crash if I used ' instead of " :)